# implementation of ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

i want to show A abd B as  my options list from the below

```
$scope.devices={
    "A": {
        "status": 3,
        "event": "Door was opened",
        "name": "xxxxxx ",
        "latlng": "xxxxx"
    },

    "B": {
        "status": 4,
        "event": "kitchen was opened",
        "name": "xxxxx ",
        "latlng": "xxxxx"
}
}
```

iam trying like this

```
<select ng-change="selected(prop)" style="color:black;" ng-model="prop" ng-options="item as item for item in devices">
                            <option value="">-- choose an option --</option>
                        </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have like this,

```
<label for="reason">Device</label>
   <select ng-change="selected(Device)" ng-model="Device" ng-options="key as key for (key , value) in devices"></select>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/8pnz24vXDL5KFvVKrXxN?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks man your answer was really helpful but i asked for ng-options.if u can provide that also

Comment: how can i send value  in ng-change??